Termination Reason: Client.InvalidKMSKey.InvalidState: The KMS key provided is in an incorrect state
I have the question about the KMS and iam settings
I use the terraform to build the infra, after setting up the kms and encryped them in my ec2, s3, rds, it told me the error:Status Reason: Instance became unhealthy while waiting for instance to be in InService state. Termination Reason: Client.InvalidKMSKey.InvalidState: The KMS key provided is in an incorrect state
Then I google it and try to add the policy into the kms, it will tell me that`
│ Error: updating KMS Key (2a1964c4-1d94-41fa-bc35-e024f390169e) policy: operation error KMS: PutKeyPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 7fa37973-f309-4b3c-9b3b-46f74ffbd6c0, InvalidArnException: An ARN in the specified key policy is invalid.
│ 
│   with aws_kms_key.secret_manager_key,
│   on kms.tf line 2, in resource "aws_kms_key" "secret_manager_key":
│    2: resource "aws_kms_key" "secret_manager_key" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: updating KMS Key (11622042-efa3-4f4c-ba89-614a651ec9c9) policy: operation error KMS: PutKeyPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 8a4df79f-bef2-43d7-a34d-d64584247138, InvalidArnException: An ARN in the specified key policy is invalid.
│ 
│   with aws_kms_key.ec2_kms_key,
│   on kms.tf line 48, in resource "aws_kms_key" "ec2_kms_key":
│   48: resource "aws_kms_key" "ec2_kms_key" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: updating KMS Key (7faafee5-8e51-4e2a-b104-fc835196bf37) policy: operation error KMS: PutKeyPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 0c7f4730-4dc6-485f-8e51-9bc0bc55ec04, MalformedPolicyDocumentException: The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future.
│ 
│   with aws_kms_key.rds_kms_key,
│   on kms.tf line 83, in resource "aws_kms_key" "rds_kms_key":
│   83: resource "aws_kms_key" "rds_kms_key" {
│ 
╵


╷
│ Error: updating KMS Key (020cbf71-e114-4a2f-8d0a-9cb7f2f5f965) policy: operation error KMS: PutKeyPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: b7e7a0a4-6c39-47b6-ad0e-bb23a1212076, InvalidArnException: An ARN in the specified key policy is invalid.
│ 
│   with aws_kms_key.s3_kms_key,
│   on kms.tf line 117, in resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_kms_key":
│  117: resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_kms_key" {
│ `

I have checked the arn; they are in the iam roles and arm are correct I don't know why they give me the error.
My code looks like this:
    resource "aws_kms_key" "secret_manager_key" {
  description             = "KMS key for Secrets Manager"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  rotation_period_in_days = 90
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "Allow the account to update key policy",
        Effect    = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"
        },
        Action   = [
          "kms:PutKeyPolicy"
        ],
        Resource = "*"
      },
      {
        Sid       = "Allow attachment of persistent resources"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = [
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:instance-profile/ec2_role_profile",
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
          ]
        }
        Action    = [
          "kms:Encrypt",
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:CreateGrant",
          "kms:ListGrants",
          "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ]
        Resource  = "*"
        Condition = {
          Bool = {
            "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource" = "true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "ec2_kms_key" {
  description             = "KMS key for EC2"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  rotation_period_in_days = 90
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "Allow attachment of persistent resources"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = [
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:instance-profile/ec2_role_profile",
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
          ]
        }
        Action    = [
          "kms:Encrypt",
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:CreateGrant",
          "kms:ListGrants",
          "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ]
        Resource  = "*"
        Condition = {
          Bool = {
            "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource" = "true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "rds_kms_key" {
  description             = "KMS key for RDS"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  rotation_period_in_days = 90
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "Allow attachment of persistent resources"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = [
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/aws-service-role/rds.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForRDS"
          ]
        }
        Action    = [
          "kms:Encrypt",
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:CreateGrant",
          "kms:ListGrants",
          "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ]
        Resource  = "*"
        Condition = {
          Bool = {
            "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource" = "true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_kms_key" {
  description             = "KMS key for S3"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  rotation_period_in_days = 90
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "Allow attachment of persistent resources"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = [
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:instance-profile/ec2_role_profile",
            "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
          ]
        }
        Action    = [
          "kms:Encrypt",
          "kms:Decrypt",
          "kms:CreateGrant",
          "kms:ListGrants",
          "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ]
        Resource  = "*"
        Condition = {
          Bool = {
            "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource" = "true"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "ec2_key_alias" {
  name         = "alias/ec2-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.ec2_kms_key.id
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "rds_key_alias" {
  name         = "alias/rds-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.rds_kms_key.id
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "s3_key_alias" {
  name         = "alias/s3-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.s3_kms_key.id
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "secrets_manager_key_alias" {
  name         = "alias/secrets-manager-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.secret_manager_key.id
}


This issue can occur for two reasons, the first reason is that the KMS key is disabled or is in pending deletion status, try to run aws kms describe-key --key-id <key-id> and check the key status.
the second thing is the KMS Key role by itself, it needs to give also permission to the role which needs to consume it, or simpler give it access to the full account:
{
  "Sid": "AllowRootAccountFullAccess",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<your-account-id>:root"
  },
  "Action": "kms:*",
  "Resource": "*"
}

Please recheck these two things, and see wether there's an issue there.
